# work remotely on heroku with vscode and commit changes

Tags: heroku, ssh

I want to code directly on production with VSCode, make some changes, and commit them (for fast prototyping, not a live server). I'm testing responses from external services, so I need a publicly-accessible URL.

Is that possible with heroku?

When I SSH intro Heroku from a terminal, I can't `git commit` cause I get `fatal: not a git repository`

Also, running `heroku ps:exec` on VSCode remote extension pack doesn't work.

Comment: No, that's not possible with Heroku (at least not without some very awkward hoops to jump through). And it's an antipattern on any hosting provider. Why do you want to work this way? There's a good chance this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: forgot to mention this is for rapid prototyping, not a live server (added to question)

Comment: What does that change? Why would you do rapid prototyping on Heroku instead of, say, on your local machine or a Docker container? Heroku is _not_ a remote workstation. It's a platform-as-a-service host.

Comment: because I'm testing responses from external services, is there a way to do that on my local machine?

Comment: Yes, you can use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/)

Comment: localtunnel is exactly what I need, you're right, it was an XY problem, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. if you make an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible on Heroku without some very awkward hoop-jumping. Heroku is a platform-as-a-service provider, not a remote workstation.

> I'm testing responses from external services, so I need a publicly-accessible URL

Your best bet may be to use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/).

These tools let you temporarily route traffic from a publicly-accessible address to your local development environment. At a high level, it looks something like this:

- Start your development server locally
- Start ngrok or localtunnel locally
- Take the publicly-accessible URL the tool gives you and tell the external service to use it